# find routes and distance between 2 co-ordinates using gmap api in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-maps

hi i want to create an  Web API to find the distance between two co-ordinates using G map API, where the API parameters will be two co-ordinates . I have got references using J script but ,as I only want to use C# for this API. It will be helpful if anybody give me reference or suggestions about this task which i am going to do.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this project:
[Google Maps Web Services API wrapper for .NET](https://github.com/maximn/google-maps)

Comment: thank you i used  Google Maps Distance Matrix API to figure it out :)